# Enviar float mediante json

Tags: mysql, json, nodejs, express

Estoy tratando de enviar un numero con coma mediante JSON para guardarlos en una base de datos MySQL a traves de una api rest creada en node js.

Codigo del endpoint

```
router.post('/', (req, res) => {
    const sensorData = {
        id: null,
        temperatura: req.body.temperatura,
        humedad: req.body.humedad,
        indice_calor: req.body.indice_calor,
        fecha: null,
    };

Sensor.insertMetric(sensorData, (err, data) => {
    if(data && data.insertId){
        res.status(200).json({ 
            success: true,
            data: data
        });
    } else{
        res.status(500).json({
            success: false
        });
    }
});
```

JSON que envio

```
{
    "temperatura": 2.3,
    "humedad": 2.3,
    "indice_calor": 2.3
}
```

Sin embargo en la base de datos los valores se almacenan como 0.99

Comment: ¿Podrías agregar el código de guardado en la base de datos?

Comment: Agrega la estructura de tu base de datos, y si me permites preguntarte tambien que libreria estas usando aqui: 
Sensor.insertMetric, no la conozco, Sequelize y MongoDB son las mas usadas para conexiones a bases de datos con Node.

Answer (score 0):

Si el error esta en la entrada de datos, puedes probar con `Number.parseFloat(req.body.temperatura)`. En este punto yo haría `console.log` para saber que te esta recogiendo realmente.

En el caso de que sea en base de datos, quizás no está creando bien el insert o el rango de la columna es pequeño.